# how to know the base page user is navigated from to a new page in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

In my windows phone application I want to know from which page user is navigated to a new page.I want to get the name of the from page from which user navigated to this new page ?

Any property which gives us this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NavigationService.BackStack to traverse the current Navigation Stack and figure out where you came from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.backstack(v=vs.92).aspx